# Why is there an Each modifier?

Tags: google-bigquery

From the docs:

> Normal JOIN operations require that the right-side table contains less
>   than 8 MB of compressed data. The EACH modifier is a hint that informs
>   the query execution engine that the JOIN might reference two large
>   tables. The EACH modifier can't be used in CROSS JOIN clauses.
>
> When possible, use JOIN without the EACH modifier for best
>   performance. Use JOIN EACH when table sizes are too large for JOIN.

**Why isn't that automatic?**

Is there a way to simplify this? Can I just **always use JOIN EACH** or always use JOIN (It seems I can't always use join because of the 8mb limitation written above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery parallelizes the processing of information within many servers that pass condensed information onto further servers in a tree topology. Everything ends up in a root node, and some of the BigQuery limitations come from this bottleneck: You can read "unlimited" amounts of data, but the output of a query has to fit into a single server.

(more details in the 2010 Dremel paper http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36632.html)

To overcome this limitation the EACH keyword was introduced: It forces a shuffle at the starting level, allowing the parallelization of tasks - without requiring a single output node - and allowing JOINing tables of unlimited size. This approach has some drawbacks, like losing the ability to ORDER BY the end result, as no single node will have visibility onto the whole output.

Would it be possible for BigQuery to detect when to use EACH automatically? Ideally, but for now the EACH keyword allows you to complete previously impossible operations - with the drawback of requiring your awareness of it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I super appreciate how it overcomes the explained issue and how BigQuery does all those awesome things, but exposing that modifier to me (basically just for showing off), just seems odd. 

Forgive my simple, lazy user approach but I'm basically just trying join and if I fail I'm trying join each.

Comment: Can you please explain why this query works without Each? 

SELECT TOP(wiki.title, 10), COUNT(*) FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] AS wiki JOIN [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] AS shakespeare
ON shakespeare.word = wiki.title

Comment: Because there are only 32,786 distinct words in Shakespeare's work. That's not a lot :-)